# client side verification using javascript date

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following Javascript code. This prevents the date from being empty, but I also need it to prevent the client from choosing any day before today; how do I go about that?

HTML

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="http://www.randyconnolly.com/tests/process.php" onsubmit="return submitFunction()">

<table border="1" >
<tr>
<td>Date:</td>
<td><input type="date" name="date" id="date"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="Submit" value="Submit"></td><td>Click Submit to validate this form!</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
function submitFunction(myForm)
{
var errormessage =""; // Generates Error Message if true 

/*Manages a control that allows the errormessage variable to determine*
whether or not it has been deemed true. If true, an error message will appaear
If false, the code will continue to move along and validate the data. */

if (document.getElementById('date').value=="")
{
errormessage+="Select a valid date \n"; 
document.getElementById('date').style.borderColor="red";
}
else {
    document.getElementById('date').style.borderColor="green";
}

if(errormessage!="")
{
alert(errormessage);        
return false;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/x3Lztj9u/) that implements your validation requirements

HTML

```
<input type="date">
<button>Check</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var dateElem = document.querySelector('input'),
    todayDate = new Date();

todayDate.setHours(0);
todayDate.setMinutes(0);

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    if(dateElem.value === '') {
    alert('Please choose a date!');
  } else {
    if(todayDate.getTime() > (new Date(dateElem.value)).getTime()) {
        alert('You can not choose a date prior to today!');
    } else {
        alert('Valid date :)');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I checked it in JSFiddle and it worked, but it didn't work with my code. Maybe if I provide you with the HTML part it will help.. The HTML is below:

<td><input type="date" name="date" id="date"></td> <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit"></td><td>Click Submit to validate this form!</td>

Comment: @Kaky I updated the JSFiddle to match your `html`, please accept the answer if it works.

Comment: I can't help you without knowing the issue, try to add more details describing why it's not working...

Comment: if its not too much to ask, how would the code change if i wanted someone to choose a date AFTER today (not including today)?

Comment: @Kaky Use `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)`